# Не появляются окошко редактирования X-editable

Tags: jquery, x-editable

Копировал код с http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/38/ все библиотеки нормально подключаются. Прошу указать, в чем моя ошибка.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap-editable.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
    <script src="lib/js/static/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/static/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/static/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#username').editable({
            type: 'text',
            url: '/post',
            pk: 1,
            title: 'Enter username',
            ajaxOptions: {
                type: 'put'
            }
        });

        //ajax emulation
        $.mockjax({
            url: '/post',
            responseTime: 200,
            response: function (settings) {
                console.log(settings);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin: 150px">
        <a href="#" id="username">awesome</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Как перехватить нажатие на галочку и взять значение из строки?

Comment: В браузерах вообще ошибок нет. Да, у всех библиотек статус загрузки 304.

Comment: да ладно, а ничего что вы код jquery ставите без `$(function(){});` ?

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите, как можно получить значение поля и перехватить эвент нажатия на галочку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#username').editable({
            type: 'text',
            url: '/post',
            pk: 1,
            title: 'Enter username',
            ajaxOptions: {
                type: 'put'
            }
        });

        //ajax emulation
        $.mockjax({
            url: '/post',
            responseTime: 200,
            response: function (settings) {
                console.log(settings);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> Как перехватить нажатие на галочку и взять значение из строки?

```
$("body").on("click",".editable-submit", function(){
    var text = $(this).parents(".editableform").find(".editable-input").find("input").val();
    //alert(text);
})
```